# How to send Ethereum transaction with json RPC

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

I want to send transaction to account this is the command to use :

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{parms}],"id":1}'
```

and this is the params to use :

```
params: [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
  "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```

But I don't understand in which unity are `"gas"`, `"gasPrice"`, and `"value"`

Before I can send transaction with this command :

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0],to:eth.accounts[1],value:web3.toWei(1‌​00,'ether'),data:web3.toHex('message')})
```

How can I do to do the same thing with Ethereum json rpc?

Answer (score 3):

`gasPrice` and `value` are both specified in `wei`, which is related to ether by `ether = 10^18 wei`. `gas` is just a number which signifies the amount of `gas` allocated for this transaction ("computing power"). The default gas for a transaction is 90000. Complex contract function might require more gas. If you leave the `gasPrice` empty, it will use a default your client decides.

This can be understood from your previous command too, as you used `web3.toWei(100, 'ether')`, which converts 100 ether to wei.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44754/discussion-on-answer-by-kobigurk-how-to-send-ethereum-transaction-with-json-rpc). :-)

Comment: @5chdn what for you have moved this to chat?? now there are no details!!!

Comment: Just click the link.